# Rails how to show a count in my layout from a query that is in my applicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have a counter in the top of my layout that on every page. The counter just shows the count from a query.

How can i get this method to be run on every page?

/controllers/ApplicationController.rb

```
def unviewed_count
    p 'we in unviewed_count'
    @count = Person.where("viewed = ?", '0').count
    p @count
end
```

/views/layouts/layout.html.erb

```
<%= @count %>
```

I tried `<%= @count %>` and `<%= unviewed_count%>`. The former just doesn't show anything, while the latter shows an error.

Comment: Are you using any `before_filter` in the `ApplicationController` to call the function?

Comment: No i was not. I forgot i had to do that. Not used to working in the ApplicationController since i'm newer to rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the method using a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :unviewed_count

  ....
end
```